# How do I connect a my Logitech unifying receiver keyboard/mouse to my macOS 12 mac?

Tags: keyboard, mouse

I can't connect my logitech unifying receiver keyboard (K520) to my macOS 12 mac. There is no macOS 12 download for the unifying software and the v10 unifying software version does not work. It fails to see my keyboard when I turned the keyboard off and on again.

Answer (score 7):

Try the "[Logi Bolt](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/4418089333655)" software. You can also try the [web-based application](https://www.logiwebconnect.com).